# Find the smallest positive root of a nonlinear function in python

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to find the smallest positive root for a nonlinear equation with a root at x=0. Currently, I use `fsolve` from `scipy` in a loop to try different initial conditions until a positive root is found. But this is quite inefficient and does not guarantee that the smallest positive root is found. I also considered `scipy.optimize.brentq` or other similar functionalities, but these all require finding an interval where the function has opposite signs, which I do not know how to do.

Comment: Doing this requires more information about the function in question: it might be something like log(1+x)-x/10^100, which has one positive root that cannot be predicted from its numerical behavior near 0.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I second what Davis Herring said. Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, it's hard to help properly.